# Preventing two position absolute elements from colliding

Tags: html, css

I have a created a mock of my site here where we have two elements on the screen. A logo and a form.

Both are positioned absolute, but on smaller screens, they end up colliding(or all most). I know there is no way to make a 'margin-top' on elements that have `position: absolute` so how could I put space between these two elements (allow scrolling) when viewed on smaller screens?

Here is the codepen link for you to review. I've provided as much information here as I can: **https://codepen.io/riza-khan/pen/VwPrXzo?editors=1100**

When screen is small, they almost collide (its more severe on the live version).

[image]

Comment: Why are they absolute positioned?  If they need to be relative to each other always, just put them in a table in adjacent cells or rows as required.

Comment: Totally agreed, its legacy code that I'm trying to hack to a fix.

Comment: The other reason the origin people may have written it like this it because they wanted to fix the form exactly in the center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have these as absolute, they should be relative and then once you have them lined up again you can set something like `padding-bottom: 10px;` to the image

Comment: Agreed, however, would there be a height media query that could help here? It would be a significant re-write to change this around

Comment: this is true but setting it to relative could also help him a lot with adjustments down the road, just from my experience

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioned elements are set 'relative' to the root (html, body) tags unless a parent has the css property of `position: relative` in which case they are 'relative' to that parent.

I say this because, if you set a min-height on the relative component (and in this case the body), the absolute positions stays the same regardless of how tall the element is. Therefore, no elements end up colliding.

Pretty easy fix for this particular example.